# Problems with making a string a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I have a problem where I'm trying to make a string a list again. But this is what happens

Original code:

```
string = "[1, 1]"
list1 = list(string)
print(str(list1))
```

Output: `['[', '1', ',', ' ', '1', ']']`

I expected the converted list to look like this

```
[1, 1]
```

Comment: Did you try `eval(string)` or `exec(string)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do will always break each character of the string into an element in the new list, what you need to do is parse the string as is into its list equivalent like so:

```
import json
string = "[1, 1]"
list_output = json.loads(string)
```

List is a JSON compatible data type so you can convert it back into python object, even if that list has dictionaries or other native data types.

Regards

Answer (score 2):

when you change the type of a string to a list, it splits all characters into elements of a list.

easy solution with a built-in function:

```
list1 = eval(string)
```

Comment: sorry I mistook eval for compile.
eval takes an expression as a string, evaluates it and returns the result. in this case it returns a list.

Comment: This now makes a lot more sense. I'm assuming ```eval()``` performs numerical operations as well?

Comment: @ChaddRobertson yes. it parses an expression and executes it as python code. so it performs numeric operation

Comment: @ChaddRobertson Yess eval() can be used to evaluate and execute any sort of code snippet in that string. Although this returns the desired output, eval is to be used very cautiously and is often frowned upon in production or where you are getting the value you send to eval from the user, since that opens the door for a lot of vulnerabilities. Be very careful where and how eval is used.

Comment: Just for reference: https://medium.com/swlh/hacking-python-applications-5d4cd541b3f1

Comment: Thanks to the both of you for getting back to me and for the reference - will check it out.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass a string into a list() function, it splits the string by each character. If you want a list [1, 1], then you want your string to be "11"

```
string = "11"
list1 = list(string)
print(str(list1))
```

Output:

```
[1, 1]
```

Comment: Even though this would work, you are asking to change the base string object in a way that the approach would work, rather, the approach should be changed based on the object that you have. Let's say this was the response from a 3rd party API, we could not go and ask them to change the structure of the response to match our approach.

Comment: Good point! I was simply thinking of the correct string to split, but if you are given the string as an input, then this approach would not work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid any imports, you can do this:

```
string = "[1, 1]"
new_list = [int(i) for i in string[1:-1].split(',')]
```

This will output:

```
[1, 1]
```